# Schedule local notification using backgroundfetch

Tags: codenameone, localnotification

When local notification is scheduled from backgroundfetch app will not restore after notification is tapped, when i schedule it in foreground it is working fine. Is there any way to make localnotification work properly when is scheduled using backgroundfetch?

thanks

Comment: Which platform are you referring to?  (iOS or Android).  Please elaborate on what you mean by "app will not restore". Does that mean the app doesn't open?  Or does it mean that the app opens to a different "place" than you expect?